# React Native Webview routing from a Webview to another Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-native

I'm working on a React Native page that's rendered in a Webview. My problem is that this page (`/about`) has links that'll open things like `/:id` but doesn't open them as a Webview. Here's my `About` component:

```
export const About = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView edges={['right', 'top', 'left']} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Webview url={`${BASE_URL}/about`} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

As things currently stand, I want `/:id` to be opened in a Webview as well, which has all the various overrides that I want. After digging into react-router-native, I've set up something like:

```
export const About = () => {
  return (
    <NativeRouter>
      <SafeAreaView edges={['right', 'top', 'left']} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          // no idea if this link is necessary?
          <Link to="/:id" />
          <Webview url={`${BASE_URL}/about`} />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" element={OtherWebview} />
        </Switch>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NativeRouter>
  )
}
```

But that ended up causing errors elsewhere. I'd love some help on determining if I'm going down the right direction. I have limited experience with React Router, so your input is greatly appreciated. Again, all I want to figure out is a clean way to open the pages from `/about` to also be in a Webview. I'd be happy to provide more details.

Comment: What version of `react-router`/`react-router-native` are you trying to use? It seems you are mixing v5 and v6 APIs/syntax.

Comment: both react-router and react-router-native are at v6.4.2

Comment: Ok, I think the `Switch` component is incorrect then. That *was* a v5 component. The v6 `Route` components should be wrapped in a `Routes` component, and the `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, i.e. `element={<OtherWebview />}`.

Comment: That helps a ton. The errors I was previously seeing have been resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Communicating from WebView Component to react native I think is not possible at this point until you have access to source code of webpage.

Incase you can make changes to webpage code. You can trigger `onMessage` function from  webpage i.e.

```
<script>
  const sendDataToReactNativeApp = async () => {
    // Replace {id} with your about page id
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(`{id}`);
  };
</script>
```

On React native

```
<WebView onMessage={(data) => console.log("WEBPAGE MSG: ", data)} />
```

Then you can create State varible and update it from `onMessage` i.e. `id` response which can be used for redirect to new screen or update the `WebView` Component `url` prop (How ever you like to take it on)

[onMessage Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/webview#onmessage)